# Git workflow and Acquia Dev Desktop .dd files

Tags: 8, multi-sites, version-control, acquia-dev-desktop

Using Acquia Dev Desktop I created a multisite setup. All working fine.

- I added all files to a local Git repository
- I added a .gitignore file
- I pushed all  the files to a *central remote repo*

I want to clone the *central remote repo* and make 2 instances for `Staging` and `Production` environment.

But if I look in my *central remote repo* I see in `/sites/` folder `my-subsite1-dev.dd`

1. Do I have to ignore this file? Do I have to add it to my .gitignore file so it's not being tracked? Because on my Production environment I can't use Acquia Dev Desktop anyway, can't I?